# Assign base class function pointer in derived class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have a project where I have a base class that has an array of function pointers that are unassigned.  I've created a small code sample that captures essentially what I am trying to do:

```
class base_class;
class derived_class;
using funcPtr = void (base_class::*)();
//using funcPtr2 = void (derived_class::*)();  <- I could use this instead, but the base class shouldn't know that the derived class exists...

class base_class {
public:
   void CustomBase() {
      cout << "Base class custom";
   }

   funcPtr func1;
   funcPtr func2;
};

class derived_class : public base_class {
public:
   void CustomDerived() {
      cout << "Derived class custom";
   }

   void SetupFuncPtrs() {
      func1 = &base_class::CustomBase;   // <-  This works
      (this->*func1)();

      func2 = &derived_class::CustomDerived;  // <-  This generates C2064
      (this->*func2)();
   }
};
```

Is there a way to do what I am attempting above, which is essentially to assign the function pointer from the base_class to a function within the derived class that matches the same format?  I suspect not, as we are forced to create the template that indicates the class, i.e. `void (base_class::*)();`  , but just wondering if there is a way around this.

Comment: You seem to be trying to reinvent virtual functions. Why not use the genuine article?

Comment: Try a static cast.

Comment: Let's suppose for a moment that `base_class` was able to store a pointer-to-member-function that somehow pointed to `CustomDerived()`. So this function can be invoked as long as we have a `base_class*` (not necessarily `this`). Suppose there is another class derived from `base_class` that does not implement such a function, perhaps `class other_class : public base_class {}`. What happens when `base_class` attempts to invoke the pointed-to function using a `base_class` pointer that happens to point to an instance of `other_class`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , I don't think this is along the lines of Virtual functions as I am essentially trying to have a the base_class function pointer array point to something that matches the signature.  The problem, clearly, is that the signature must must include base_class*:: as part of the type (I assume for C++ calling purposes).  Ideally, i'd like the using type to be: `using funcPtr = void (*)();` , but we can't do that for C++ classes, perhaps I just need re-work in regular C.

@JaMiT, yep, thanks.  I'll have to re-think the design it seems.  This is ported from C#, where this is doable.

Comment: Well, you could store `std::function<void()>`, it can wrap both the member function and the object pointer to call it on. In fact, it could wrap arbitrary callable, quite possibly unrelated to either `base_class` or `derived_class` (just like `void (*)()` could point to an arbitrary function). I still don't understand the point of the exercise - this is a strange thing to want to do, sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems, I can achieve what I need by using `reinterpret_cast<>`

i.e. change the following line:

```
func2 = &derived_class::CustomDerived;  // <-  This generates C2064
```

to:

```
func2 = reinterpret_cast<funcPtr>(&derived_class::CustomDerived);
```

In this case I am "answering" my own question.  I am by no means suggesting this is the best solution or indeed whether the design itself is the best, I am simply indicating a mechanism that works for my particular scenario.